# Unhandled exception while reading structures

Tags: c++, exception, structure, unhandled

The program throws an unhandled exception on this line:

```
}else if(s == "backpack"){
    cout << "\nEquipped items: " << endl;
    cout << weapon->Name << endl << cArmour->Name << endl; //this line
```

It prints 'Equipped items: ' then throws an exception. This file - Player.h - includes Library.h, which in turn includes Globals.h, which has the structs:

```
struct sWeapon{
    std::string Name;
    int Damage;
};

struct sArmour{
    std::string Name;
    int AP;
};
```

In the Player constructor, it creates the struct objects:

```
Player::Player(std::map<std::string,sWeapon*> wepArray,std::map<std::string,sArmour*> armArray){

    weapons = wepArray;
    armour = armArray;

    weapon = wepArray["None"];
    cArmour = armArray["None"];
}
```

At the beginning of the entire program, it calls init_weapons and init_armour:

```
int main(){
    using namespace std;

    //initialise the game
    std::map<std::string,sWeapon*> wepArray = init_weapons(); //get weapon array
    std::map<std::string,sArmour*>armArray = init_armour(); //get armour array
```

which return the map of all the weapons:

```
//init_weapons()
//sets up weapons map
std::map<std::string,sWeapon*> init_weapons(void){
    std::map< std::string, sWeapon* > weapons; //map of weapons

    //starting 'none'
    sWeapon* none = new sWeapon();
    none->Name = "None";
    none->Damage = 0;

    //create weapons
    sWeapon* w1 = new sWeapon();
    w1->Name = "Rusty dagger";
    w1->Damage = 3;

    //put in map
    weapons[w1->Name] = w1;
    return weapons;
}

std::map<std::string,sArmour*> init_armour(void){
    std::map< std::string, sArmour* > armour; //map of armour

    //starting 'none'
    sArmour* none = new sArmour();
    none->Name = "None";
    none->AP = 0;

    //create armour
    sArmour* a1 = new sArmour();
    a1->Name = "Leather";
    a1->AP = 10;

    //put in map
    armour[a1->Name] = a1;
    return armour;
}
```

then passes those maps as arguments to the player constructor shown above.

Comment: What exception does it throw?  Please paste this in the question.  You can chop off the nasty bits if you want, since C++ error messages are often gigantic.

Comment: @First comment - Access violation reading location somenumbers.

Comment: Where are the weapons and armors deallocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing either `weapon` or `cArmour` is null or point nowhere.

That's all more likely since you're not storing your "None" weapon and armor in your global hash.

Try printing out the pointer for those two "None" objects, then the pointer values for the object members `weapon` or `cArmour`.

Comment: Pig Head: I'd +1 again, but I can't :) You add `w1` and `a1` to the maps, but don't add `none` to either map.

Comment: That'd be the problem then! Thanks